# Ubuntu 20.04 with UHD Graphics 630 using MST hub gives jagged tear on one screen

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, multiple-monitors, monitor

I'm new to Ubuntu 20.04 and have a PC with

- UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)
- and 2 display ports.
- Also, I have 3 ASUS monitors.

  - One is 4K and
  - the other is a Pro Art with 1920x1200 resolution.

One of the display ports uses a Startech MST HUB. No matter how the cables and splitters are arranged, at least one of the Pro Art monitors has a very jagged tear (bottom half of the screen torn and shifted left).

Also have an ASUS PC running windows. It's older, so, using it's graphics card (a replacement from the original) to flawlessly drive the monitors with DVI/HDMI/VGA ports. After swapping around the ports and cable, pretty sure it's not a monitor fault. All this suggests it's not the cabling or MTS hub.

If the resolution of the effected monitor is reduced from 1920x1200 to 1280x1024, the jaggedness disappears. Reducing the resolution of the 4K screen doesn't buy me any real estate on the effected montior. Again, there are no problems accommodating the higher resolution in Windows.

I tried updating the software, but it reports that everything is up to date. Any suggestions on how to fix or insights to what is causing the problem?

Comment: This same issue is reported here : https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/ThinkCentre-M720s-Intel-UHD-Graphics-630-not-recognized-by-K-ubuntu-20-04-LTS/m-p/5014367  see if this helps

Comment: Thanks.  This is a work machine and changing back to 19 and then upgrading to 20.04 is not really an option for me.